# How the @,x,X directives work with Ruby pack()/unpack() method?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I just went through the [Ruby Doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-frozen-3F). But there is no sufficient code to understand how the below three are used in Real life programming:

`@`,`X`,`x`.

can anyone explain it with a simple snippet?

Thanks

Comment: You need to be equally interested in String#unpack. I understood that these are for creating and reading binaries, I have never used them yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will give you few example and will be learning together with you:

```
[1,2,3,4].pack("CCCC")
=> "\x01\x02\x03\x04"
```

So serializes in unsigned chars. Every letter in new byte.

```
[1,2,3,4].pack("CCXCC")
=> "\x01\x03\x04"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CCXXC")
=> "\x03"
```

Think of the 'X' as backspace directive

```
[1,2,3,4].pack("CCxC")
=> "\x01\x02\x00\x03"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CCxxC")
=> "\x01\x02\x00\x00\x03"
```

'x' places zero valued byte.

```
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@C")
=> "\x01\x03"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@@C")
=> "\x01\x03"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@@CC")
=> "\x01\x03\x04"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@CC")
=> "\x01\x03\x04"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@C@C")
=> "\x01\x04"
[1,2,3,4].pack("CC@C@@C")
=> "\x01\x04"
```

'@' seems to be a single backspace, but will not support multiple operations at one time. The last  one as explanation does not relate at all with the text from the documentation:

> @           Moves to absolute position

But is what it seems to be doing.

**EDIT** BTW `@` seems a lot more logical when looked in the context of `unpack`:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].pack("CCCCC").unpack("CCC@CCCCC@CC")
=> [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Starts unpacking from the very beginning once more.

**EDIT2** And here goes the explanation of the other two directives in the context of unpacking:

```
[1,2,3,4,5].pack("CCCCC").unpack("CCCXC")
=> [1, 2, 3, 3]
[1,2,3,4,5].pack("CCCCC").unpack("CCCXXC")
=> [1, 2, 3, 2]
[1,2,3,4,5].pack("CCCCC").unpack("CCCxC")
=> [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

So 'x' ignores the next to decode byte and 'X' will make the previous byte the next to read once more. 'X' can stack.

Here goes my first attempt of summarizing the results:

`pack`:

- 'x' places zero byte
- 'X' works like backspace directive, meaning the previous byte is not going to be packed actually
- '@' has unexplainable behaviour for me

`unpack`:

- 'x' Skips the next byte that was for unpacking
- 'X' moves the reader backwards, meaning the last read byte will be read once more.
- '@' moves the reader to the very beginning. That means that all the bytes will be unpacked once more.

***NOTE*** Reader is a word I made up for ease of explanation and is, by no means, formal.

**EDIT3** Here goes the explanation of "\x01" notation too:

```
a = [17, 22, 31]
=> [17, 22, 31]
a.pack("CCC")
=> "\x11\x16\x1F"
```

It seems like this stands for hexadecimal representation. And all the site I have linked to use decimal representation apparently. Otherwise, as it can be seen those are the hexadecimal representations of the given numbers.

Comment: why `\x` is coming preceed to every number in the output.

Comment: @CodeLover I think this is the way my irb is configured. Usually I would expect one more 0 there, not `x`

Comment: I am also getting the same output,but why `1` represented as `\x01`. that i want to learn! then i will ask you more questions on it.

Comment: @CodeLover I somehow think it is just a matter of configuration. If I run all the examples form http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-pack and http://www.example8.com/category/view/id/13867 I get all the Xs, still the examples claim zeroes. Btw I added one more edit.

Comment: I just accepted your answer, really you are awesome!! :) your post should earned from here 2000+ vote in near future, what about mine I don't know ;-). But i got my answer,Ruby developer should use this to their documentation to make their one more appreciable!

Comment: @CodeLover I added third edit with explanation of the Xs and the encoding strategy.

Comment: Yes, I am now reading and putting all the logic to my brain! :) now if possible can you look at another post in `SO` which some one post here - [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293926/how-does-pack-and-unpack-work-in-ruby/14294172#comment19853284_14294172). If you answer it then, it may be helpful for me also, as i was also trying to understand how the directives work in Ruby, but couldn't try out,doc has nothing at all about it.