# How the floating point directive works in Ruby packing()/unpacking()?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

Can any one here help me out to understand how the below floating point directives work in Ruby with `packing() and unpacking()` method?

- `D and d`
- `F and f`
- `g and G`
- `e and E`

***I have tried below:***

```
irb(main):001:0> [2,44,43].pack('D')
=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@"
irb(main):002:0> [2,44,43].pack('d')
=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@"
irb(main):004:0> [2,44,43].pack('ddd')
=> "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00F@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\
x80E@"
irb(main):005:0> [2,44,43].pack('fff')
=> "\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x000B\x00\x00,B"
irb(main):006:0> [2,44,43].pack('FFF')
=> "\x00\x00\x00@\x00\x000B\x00\x00,B"
irb(main):007:0> [2,44,43].pack('ggg')
=> "@\x00\x00\x00B0\x00\x00B,\x00\x00"
irb(main):008:0> [2,44,43].pack('GGG')
=> "@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@F\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@E\x80\x00\x00\x00\x0
0\x00"
irb(main):009:0>
```

How the output is coming? what the logic of such computation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-unpack) are you having trouble with?

Comment: Yes, there they just shown some of the directives with examples, but not all of my list. So as a newbie to this platform of `ruby` I would like to really know how exactly these works,what the logic are incurred with them?

Comment: Have you tried to use them in combination with a hex dumper? They work the same way as they do in Python and Perl: they convert native types to and from raw bits.

Comment: Can you please help me here with some tiny codes. I am not educated with perl or python too.your help can give a good start to explore with them more!

Comment: Why don't you try these out in `irb`? Most people you are asking don't know how these work either. The trick to find out is using `irb` to test them. So what have you tried, and what is it specifically you do not understand about these methods? Your question has too broad a scope.

Comment: Don't close this post, I just updated my description! hope people around `SO` will now understand what I am trying to understand! please don't vote the post for close!

Comment: What the bad making people to vote it as down? if any issue to understand what i am looking for to have here,please ask me. not to try the bad habit `DOWN VOTE`.

Comment: Briefly: floats have a binary representation that the computer, C, and C++ understand and another representation that Ruby understands; `pack` and `unpack` are used to convert between those two. They're generally used for reading/writing binary files and speaking binary network protocols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those directives convert the numbers in the array to a floating point byte representation.

If you want to learn what is happening you can watch this video:

**Floating Point Representation: Example**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-8fMtUNX1A

And read this article:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/floating-point-representation-basics/

Through Google I found the above answers for you by [searching for "floating point representation"](https://www.google.com/search?q=floating+point+representation).

---

Just to give you an example:

```
> [2.0].pack('f').bytes.map(&:to_i)
=> [0, 0, 0, 64]
```

This is a floating point number which is represented in hexadecimal as:

```
0x40000000
```

Where you can see that `64` is `0x40` in hexadecimal.

In order to understand why `2.0` becomes `0x40000000` you have to understand how computers convert floating point numbers into binary representations.

You can use this page to test it out:
http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

For example here is what is looks like for `2.0`:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/qWqFM.png]

Comment: No,I am giving you one post,see how someone answered to that post. and i didn't find any answers of my above post,thus posted. have look at the explanation. Please dont down vote me! [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294988/how-the-x-x-directives-work-with-ruby-pack-unpack-method).

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU I read that answer. This cannot be answered that simply. Please watch the video (10 minutes) and you will see it is not that simple.

Comment: okay!let it opened then,hope anyone surely can answer here,don't down vote, its made my post bad to see! BTW I am looking into the video!

Comment: @PythonLikeYOU - Watch the video then see my edited answer.