# Understanding bytes unpack

Tags: ruby, networking, server-side

I found such code in: https://github.com/mojombo/proxymachine/

```
proxy do |data|
  return  if data.size < 9
  v, c, port, o1, o2, o3, o4, user = data.unpack("CCnC4a*")
  return { :close => "\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0" }  if v != 4 or c != 1
  return  if ! idx = user.index("\0")
  { :remote => "#{[o1,o2,o3,o4]*'.'}:#{port}",
    :reply => "\0\x5a\0\0\0\0\0\0",
    :data => data[idx+9..-1] }
end
```

What does this code do? Especially these lines:

`data.unpack("CCnC4a*")`

`return { :close => "\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0" }  if v != 4 or c != 1`

`:reply => "\0\x5a\0\0\0\0\0\0",
        :data => data[idx+9..-1] }`

I am not asking for ruby idioms, but for the functional side.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14293926/how-does-pack-and-unpack-work-in-ruby but is not a duplicate IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a String, the `unpack` method is defined in [`String#unpack`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-unpack).

```
v, c, port, o1, o2, o3, o4, user = data.unpack("CCnC4a*")
```

This converts a String (throug reading the bytes, not interpreting the string as a text) into an array following these rules:

- `C`: read 8-bit as an unsigned char
- `C`: read 8-bit as an unsigned char
- `n`: read 16-bit unsigned integer (in big-endian format)
- `C4`: read 8-bit as an unsigned char (4 times)
- `a*`: read all the remaining bytes as an arbitrary string

So we get an array containing 8 entries (7 integers, one string). Each of those entries in the array is assigned to the variables `v`, `c`, `port`, `o1`, `o2`, `o3`, `o4`, `user`.

```
return { :close => "\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0" }  if v != 4 or c != 1
```

When `v` is not `4` and `c` is not `1`, return the hash `{ :close => "\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0" }`.

A method returns the result of its last statement. The last statement of your method is

```
{ :remote => "#{[o1,o2,o3,o4]*'.'}:#{port}",
  :reply => "\0\x5a\0\0\0\0\0\0",
  :data => data[idx+9..-1] }
```

It is a hash containing three keys (`:remote`, `:reply`, `:data`). In an earlier statement we assigned `idx` so that it contains the position of the first null-byte (`"\0"`) in the `data` string.

`data[idx+9..-1]` returns the part of the `data` string beginning at 9 bytes after the first null-byte until the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks for great anwser! What exactly `"\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0"` means?

Comment: `"\0\x5b\0\0\0\0\0\0"` is a string containing lots of null-bytes (`\0`) and the byte `0x5b`.